# Dropdown `value` must be an array when `multiple` is set. Received type: `[object Undefined]`

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui-react

I'm using **Semantic-ui-react**, I am getting

> Dropdown `value` must be an array when `multiple` is set. Received type: `[object Undefined]

```
<Dropdown id={id + 'baa'}
    fluid selection
    search={true} 
    minCharacters={0} 
    multiple={false}
    loading={isDataBeingFetched} 
    disabled={!isOwnerView || isDataBeingFetched}
    options={options1}
    placeholder={'Select an Approver'}
    value={currentItem.baa_approver}
    onChange={(event, { value }) =>
    this.handleOnChange(currentIndex, value, 'baa_approver', event)}
 />
```

Comment: The error states that `value` attribute should be an array, but currently it's an undefined object.  You may want to revisit `currentItem.baa_approver` value..

Comment: Its in foreach (currentItem). I am checking whether its undefined or not. but still getting same Error

Comment: Hi @Ramya. Were you able to fix this? I'm getting the same console error when the value is an array. Seems like a bug. Updating `semantic-ui-react` to the latest version didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

use `defaultValue={currentItem.baa_approver}` instead of `value={currentItem.baa_approver}`